conversion xml(longvarchar) a sdt
me encuentro trabajando con genexus 15(java), estoy teniendo problemas con el metodo fromxml de genexus
tengo la siguiente extructura de xml en una variable longvarchar
    <SDT_BECreMultipleSelection xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">
    <SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">
        <Selected>false</Selected>
        <BECreNroTi>410054</BECreNroTi>
        <BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>
        <BECreNroFa>553606</BECreNroFa>
        <BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>
        <BECreNroAf>00001034</BECreNroAf>
        <BECreNomAp>DIOCARES CAMPOS GABRIEL</BECreNomAp>
        <BECreOrDescripcion/>
    </SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>
    <SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">
        <Selected>false</Selected>
        <BECreNroTi>550343</BECreNroTi>
        <BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>
        <BECreNroFa>554860</BECreNroFa>
        <BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>
        <BECreNroAf>00001130</BECreNroAf>
        <BECreNomAp>CASTILLO CARDENAS LUANA</BECreNomAp>
        <BECreOrDescripcion/>
    </SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>
    <SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">
        <Selected>false</Selected>
        <BECreNroTi>544051</BECreNroTi>
        <BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>
        <BECreNroFa>555073</BECreNroFa>
        <BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>
        <BECreNroAf>00001143</BECreNroAf>
        <BECreNomAp>RODRIGUEZ MONDACA FAUSTINA LUJÁN</BECreNomAp>
        <BECreOrDescripcion/>
    </SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>
    <SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">
        <Selected>false</Selected>
        <BECreNroTi>551255</BECreNroTi>
        <BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>
        <BECreNroFa>555834</BECreNroFa>
        <BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>
        <BECreNroAf>00001170</BECreNroAf>
        <BECreNomAp>LEIVA ALMA XIOMARA</BECreNomAp>
        <BECreOrDescripcion/>
    </SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>
</SDT_BECreMultipleSelection>

cree el siguiente SDT con la siguiente extructura

en un procedimiento utilizo el siguiente codigo, pero el sdt queda siempre vacio y la variable booleana &xmlasdt siempre retorna "false". agradesco desde ya cualquier ayuda. Saludos
&xmlasdt=&SDT_BeCreMultipleSelection.FromXml(&xml,&messages)
&xmlreader1.Close()
msg("mensaje"+&messages)
msg("sepudo convertir xml a sdt? "+&xmlasdt.ToString())


Ese xml lo genera la misma kb o viene de otro? Porque seguro son los xmlns que no coinciden

el XML es tomado desde una base dedatos postgres, tipo de dato text. realizando pruebas corrobore que si cargo de forma manual el xml la funcion fromXML de genexus funciona correctamente, pero al leerlo desde la tabla de postgres. creo que debe ser por los caracteres especiales. o puede que alla algun error con la conversion de los formatos de codificacion de caracteres

Para que no haya diferencias en el SDT creado, te recomiendo pasar ese XML a XSD y luego importar el XSD desde Tools > Application Integration > XML Schema Import.
El XSD sería:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="com.tekhne.beneficiarios" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SDT_BECreMultipleSelection">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Selected" type="xs:boolean" />
              <xs:element name="BECreNroTi" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="BECreOrCodigo" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="BECreNroFa" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="BECreNroSe" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="BECreNroAf" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
              <xs:element name="BECreNomAp" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="BECreOrDescripcion" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Eso lo guardas como un archivo .XSD y luego lo importas con XML Schema Import:




Luego con este código funcionó de manera correcta:
Event 'Prueba XML'
    &xml = '<SDT_BECreMultipleSelection xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">'
    &xml +=     '<SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">'
    &xml +=     '<Selected>false</Selected>'
    &xml +=         '<BECreNroTi>410054</BECreNroTi>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>'
    &xml +=         '<BECreNroFa>553606</BECreNroFa>'
    &xml +=         '<BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>'
    &xml +=         '<BECreNroAf>00001034</BECreNroAf>'
    &xml +=         '<BECreNomAp>DIOCARES CAMPOS GABRIEL</BECreNomAp>'
    &xml +=         '<BECreOrDescripcion/>'
    &xml +=     '</SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>'
    &xml +=     '<SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">'
    &xml +=     '<Selected>false</Selected>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreNroTi>550343</BECreNroTi>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreNroFa>554860</BECreNroFa>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreNroAf>00001130</BECreNroAf>'
    &xml +=     '<BECreNomAp>CASTILLO CARDENAS LUANA</BECreNomAp>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreOrDescripcion/>'
    &xml +=         '</SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>'
    &xml +=         '<SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">'
    &xml +=             '<Selected>false</Selected>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroTi>544051</BECreNroTi>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroFa>555073</BECreNroFa>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroAf>00001143</BECreNroAf>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNomAp>RODRIGUEZ MONDACA FAUSTINA LUJÁN</BECreNomAp>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreOrDescripcion/>'
    &xml +=         '</SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>'
    &xml +=         '<SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem xmlns="com.tekhne.beneficiarios">'
    &xml +=             '<Selected>false</Selected>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroTi>551255</BECreNroTi>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreOrCodigo>1</BECreOrCodigo>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroFa>555834</BECreNroFa>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroSe>1</BECreNroSe>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNroAf>00001170</BECreNroAf>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreNomAp>LEIVA ALMA XIOMARA</BECreNomAp>'
    &xml +=             '<BECreOrDescripcion/>'
    &xml +=         '</SDT_BECreMultipleSelectionItem>'
    &xml +=         '</SDT_BECreMultipleSelection>'
    
    &SDT_BECreMultipleSelection.FromXml(&xml.Trim(),&messages)
    msg("mensaje"+&messages)
    msg("sepudo convertir xml a sdt? " + &SDT_BECreMultipleSelection.ToXml())
EndEvent


hola Guido, muchas gracias por tu aporte, es correcto de esta manera funciona si es que la variable &xml es cargada de la manera que mostras. En mi caso estoy cargando esta variable del tipo longvarchar desde una BD postgres tipo de dato text, y por lo que noto debo tener algun tipo de error en la interpretacion de los caracteres especiales ya que a mi si leo este dato desde la DB sigue sin funcionar. desde ya muchas gracias cuando pueda solucionarlo publicare como lo hice
